# Reading a specific data to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Hello I would like to convert this data to dataframe in python. I would like to have 4 columns named: problem, language, time and size. Each row should contain 4 values.
The data looks like this:
problem,language,time,size,
n-body,C,2.13,1633,

Comment: I removed Julia tag as it is not Julia related. Perhaps have a look at Pandas tutorial as it is the first line of the tutorial

Comment: Use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do it (as requested in the question)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"problem": ["n-body"], "language": ["C"], "time": [2.13], "size": [1633]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The best option would be to create a CSV with the required data and read it in using the `pd.read_csv()` method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html